# Why I get error, when I'm trying to have overlapped density plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r

I want to create overlaped density plot. I decided to use ggplot2.

My data are in data frame formate.
Here How they are look:

```
Ge<-data.frame(Ge)
dim(Ge)
#[1] 100   1
Ge[1:4,]
#[1]   6.005409  38.681342 102.079283 185.672611
dim(Tr)
#[1] 100   1
Tr[1:4,]
#[1] 12.8678547  1.3034715  1.1372413  0.7973491
```

Here is my code to create plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x=x), colour="red", data=Tr) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=x), colour="blue", data=Ge)
```

But this is the error I get it:

```
    Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous
Error: stat_density requires the following missing aesthetics: x
```

Would someone help me to solve this ?

Comment: Is `x` the name of the column in each data frame? Try names `names(Ge)` and `names(Tr)`. In my example I just directly referred to the column that I wanted, `Ge[,1]` and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a single data frame where ever possible with ggplot. That is the logic behind the syntax, but is unintuitive at first. Considering your sample code, `Tr` and `Ge` are factors and there is one set of values which you're representing on a common x-axis.

The reshape2 package has a handy tool for combining separate data into a format suitable for ggplot plotting, `melt`. Check out the package documentation, but see below for working code and a sample output.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
Ge=runif(n=100)
Tr=runif(n=100)
data=data.frame(Ge,Tr)
names(data)=c('Ge','Tr')
data=melt(data,id.vars=NULL)
ggplot(data,aes(x=value,fill=variable))+geom_density(alpha=.4)
```

[image]

There is a book by Hadley Wickham which covers all of this information in excellent detail. [Amazon link](http://amzn.com/0387981403?tag=ggplot2-20)

**Update**
I have more closely replicated the OP's code (straying away from best practices) and still get a functional plot, though with a warning.

```
Ge=data.frame(runif(n=100))
Tr=data.frame(runif(n=120))

ggplot()+geom_density(aes(data=Ge,x=Ge[,1]),color='red')+
  geom_density(aes(data=Tr,x=Tr[,1]),color='blue')
```

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
>   data.frame. Defaulting to continuous Don't know how to automatically
>   pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous

[image]

Comment: But how is the Ge and Tr have different length ?

Comment: Can you update your question with a reproducible example of what `Ge` and `Tr` are? Have you tried the plot with only `Tr` and then only `Ge`? How do those tests work out?

Comment: I updated my answer testing your code and it works for me. Perhaps there are some issues with your data frames. Are any of the values `NA` or of a different type than numeric? Try `summary(Ge)` and `summary(Tr)`.

Comment: I checked, there is no NA, but the values are in the format of :  3.848143e-01 , .....

Comment: Test out plotting only `Tr` and then only `Ge`. Let me know how those work. Also, does my original post fix your problem?